# Karma compile errors on Angular/Cordova project - cannot find name "X" ('FileError', 'Entry', DirectoryEntry', etc)

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, karma-jasmine, karma-webpack

I am attempting to retrofit an existing Angular 6/Cordova project with Karma/Jasmine. I have installed all the prerequisites and packages and configured all the package config files. I have the karma test runner working, but now I am getting a bunch of type dependency errors in my Karma compile output (see below).

I have a simple .spec.ts file created as simple test to see if the framework is working:

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, inject, tick } from "@angular/core/testing";

// import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions } from "@angular/http";
import {FeedbackService} from "../services";
import * as http from "http";


describe("FeedbackService", () => {
  // let mockResponse, matchingHero, connection;

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [ FeedbackService],
  }));

  it("should return current language code", inject([FeedbackService], service => {
    expect(service.getLanguageCode()).toContain("en-US");
  }));
});
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
> ng test --sourcemap=true

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active29 05 2018 16:44:07.646:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
29 05 2018 16:44:07.655:INFO [karma]: Karma v2.0.2 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
29 05 2018 16:44:07.656:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
29 05 2018 16:44:07.662:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome                                         [../../../../../src/polyfills.ts] ./src/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {polyfills} [built]
   [0] multi ./src/polyfills.ts 28 bytes {polyfills} [built]
[../../../../../src/test.ts] ./src/test.ts 0 bytes {main} [built]

ERROR in src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(35,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Entry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(87,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(92,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(105,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(141,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(189,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(215,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(245,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(257,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(262,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(408,16): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(408,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(411,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(428,23): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(429,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DirectoryEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(431,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(433,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileWriter'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(476,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(497,16): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(497,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(518,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(521,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(529,16): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(529,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DirectoryEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(532,51): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Entry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(542,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(545,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(553,16): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(553,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(559,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(562,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(615,16): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(616,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DirectoryEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(620,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(627,36): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(628,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DirectoryEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(631,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DirectoryEntry'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(642,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(647,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(695,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FileError'.
src/app/core/services/storage.service.ts(724,24): error TS2339: Property 'resolveLocalFileSystemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

Here is my karma.config.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri May 25 2018 09:18:40 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
    ],

    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'src/app/**/*spec.ts',
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
      "./src/app/sandbox/*.ts",
      "./src/app/core/containers/app-cordova.ts",
      "./src/app/app-cordova.module.ts",
      "./src/main-cordova.ts"
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Here is my angular.cli.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "ngease"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "web",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.web.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "ease",
      "styles": [
        "styles/styles.scss"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "styles"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "local": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
        "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts",
        "preprod": "environments/environment.preprod.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "mobile",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "www",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "assets-cordova",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index-cordova.html",
      "main": "main-cordova.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.mobile.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles/styles.scss",
        "styles-cordova/styles.scss"
      ],
      "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
          "styles"
        ]
      },
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "local": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
        "uat": "environments/environment.uat.ts",
        "preprod": "environments/environment.preprod.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

test.ts:

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare const __karma__: any;
declare const require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

And finally my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ease-app",
  "version": "1.23.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ng test --sourcemap=true",
    "start": "npm run ng:web:serve",
    "ng:web:serve": "ng serve --app=web --env=local --port 8080",
    "ng:web:build": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=web --env=prod --prod",
    "ng:web:build:dev": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=web --env=dev --sourcemaps --build-optimizer=false",
    "ng:web:build:uat": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=web --env=uat --prod",
    "ng:web:build:preprod": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=web --env=preprod --prod",
    "ng:mobile:build": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=mobile --env=prod --prod",
    "ng:mobile:build:preprod": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=mobile --env=preprod --prod",
    "ng:mobile:build:uat": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=mobile --env=uat --prod",
    "ng:mobile:build:dev": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=mobile --env=dev --build-optimizer=false",
    "ng:mobile:build:local": "increase-memory-limit && ng build --app=mobile --env=local --build-optimizer=false",
    "cordova:ios:iphone5": "cordova run ios --debug --emulator --target=iPhone-5s",
    "cordova:ios:iphone6": "cordova run ios --debug --emulator --target=iPhone-6",
    "cordova:ios:iphone8+": "cordova run ios --debug --emulator --target=iPhone-8-Plus",
    "cordova:ios:ipad": "cordova run ios --debug --emulator --target=iPad--5th-generation-"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.8",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.4.6",
    "@ngrx/effects": "5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "5.2.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
    "angular-gridster2": "^4.3.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.3.2",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-universal-links-plugin": "file:Library/cordova-universal-links-plugin",
    "cordova-windows": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.1",
    "ngx-treeview": "^2.0.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.0.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^1.3.2",
    "@types/cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.44",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.73",
    "@types/node": "^9.3.0",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.7",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "del-cli": "1.1.0",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.6",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.1",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "windows",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Upload pictures to your audit.",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "uses photos"
      },
      "cordova-universal-links-plugin": {}
    }
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "BeforeBuild": [
      "build:appdebug",
      "notify:readyforcordovaprepare"
    ],
    "Clean": [
      "clean"
    ],
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "update"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea why I am still getting these errors is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: project compiles fine locally using npm-cli when not running Karma.

Comment: OK we solved it here. I will post the solution for anyone else out there that comes across this issue.

We needed to added the Cordova type definitions to the tsconfig.spec.json file:

"types": [
      "cordova",
      "cordova-plugin-file",
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs",
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]